# html table showing white space between cell in cubecart ecommerce

Tags: html, html-table

This is my code if you try it it works well in this form.

```
<table style="width=183; heigth:200; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; border-collapse: collapse;" >
<tr>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="2" style="width:14px; height:60px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_1x1.jpg" style="width:14px; height:60px; border:0;" alt=""/></td>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width:152px; height:60px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_1x2.jpg" style="width:152px; height:60px; border:0;"  alt=""/></td>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width:17px; height:60px; padding:0; "><img  src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_1x3.jpg" style="width=17px; height:60px; border:0;"  alt=""/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="2" style="width:14px; height:90px; padding:0; vertical-align:top; border:0; background-image:url(http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_2x1.jpg); background-position:top border: 0; background-repeat:repeat-y;"></td>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width:152px; height:90px; vertical-align:top; border:0; background-color: #feed01; padding:0; " ></td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:17px; height:90px; padding:0; vertical-align:top; border:0; background-image:url(http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_2x3.jpg); background-position:top border: 0; background-repeat:repeat-y;"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="2" style="width:14px; height:6px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_3x1.jpg" style="width:14px; height:6px; border:0;" alt="" /></td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:152px; height:6px; padding: 0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_3x2.jpg" style="width:152px; height:6px; border:0;" alt="" /></td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:17px; height6px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_3x3.jpg" style="width:17px; height:6px; border:0;"  alt="" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width:13px; height:58px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_4x1.jpg" style="width:13px; height:58px border:0;" alt="" /></td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="2" style="width:153px; height:58px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_4x2.jpg" style="width:153px; height:58px border:0;" alt="" /></td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:17px; height:58px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/box_4x3.jpg" style="width:17px; height:58px; border:0;" alt="" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="width:13px; height:1px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/blank.gif" style="width:13px; height:1px; border:0;" alt=""/></td>
<td style="width:1px; height:1px; padding:0;"><img  src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/blank.gif" style="width:1px; height:1px; border:0;" alt=""/></td>
<td style="width:152px; height:1px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/blank.gif" style="width:152px; height:1px; border:0;" alt=""/></td>
<td style="width:17px; height:1px; padding:0;"><img src="http://www.pcutile.it/images/blank.gif" style="width:17px; height:1px border:0;" alt=""/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

All seems ok, but when I insert it inside a template of cubecart it show same strange white space between cell of table. Anyone know why? You can see it in http://www.pcutile.it

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code and I found a couple of ways how to fix your problem. I assume that you are using the HTML5 DOCTYPE.This DOCTYPE renders images differently and is causing the space between your table rows.

You can chose between the following options:

> *Change the DOCTYPE into:*   `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
>     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Or if you need to keep this doctype for some reason, you can use one of the following to fix your problem.

> *Add:*    `display:block;`    to every image-tag in your code
>
> *Add:*    `line-height:0;`    to the style of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to your table `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` should help:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width=183; heigth:200; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; border-collapse: collapse;" >
```